# MYSQL - Modify query - Pass parameter to outer query instead of subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, spring-data-jpa

I have a table all_inventory with below structure.

```
id,date,ProductId, product_name,warehouseid, closingstock
'1','2021-05-06','500972','Window Grill (3 X 4)','21','0'
'2','2021-05-06','500953','Window Grill (4 X 4)','21','8'
'3','2021-05-06','500935','Window Grill (3.6 X 3)','21','1'
'4','2021-05-06','500937','Window Grill (3 X 5)','21','5'
'5','2021-05-06','500945','Window Grill (5 X 4)','21','3'
'6','2021-05-06','501217','Round Ventilation','21','0'
'10','2021-05-06','501217','Round Ventilation','21','1'
```

Combination of ProductId and warehouseid can be repeated.

I want to fetch closing stock for any past date. i.e addition of latest closingstock of all warehouses where productid is same. So, I wrote a group by query to find MIN(id) - this will give me latest record with combination of productid and warehoused. Then self joined the table based on id. Below is the query which is working fine.

```
select
        ai1.id,
        ai1.ProductId as productId,
        ai1.product_name,
        ROUND(SUM(ai1.closingstock),2) as totalQuantityInHand
FROM all_inventory ai1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        Productid,
        warehouseid,
        MIN(id) as id
    FROM all_inventory ai
    WHERE ai.date<='2021-03-01'
    GROUP BY Productid,warehouseid
    ) AS ai2  ON ai1.id=ai2.id
GROUP BY ai1.ProductId,ai1.product_name;
```

Now, the problem is, I want to use this query with Hibernate as a view. So, I cannot pass parameters to subqueries (see ai.date='2021-03-01'. This is a parameter). Parameter should be passed to outer query. Can this query be re-written such that there are no subqueries involved?

Comment: I would suggest that you use two views for this.  Although this can be written without a subquery, the performance is likely to be . . . distasteful.

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: Mysql version  8